# Mock file in Storage to download in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Is there a way to mock a file using Laravels `Storage::fake()` method?

I have used https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mocking#storage-fake as a base for my tests, which works fine for uploads. But my download tests are ugly as I have to run my upload route first every time with a mock upload `UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg')`. Is there a way to skip that part and mock the file to exist directly in the fake storage system?

```
public function testAvatarUpload()
{
    Storage::fake('avatars');

    // This is the call I would like to change into a mocked existing uploaded file
    $uploadResponse = $this->json('POST', '/avatar', [
        'avatar' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg')
    ]);

    // Download the first avatar
    $response = $this->get('/download/avatar/1');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I might be late here. but wanted to help others visiting this question to give an idea of implementing it.

Here is a sample with some assertions.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Upload;

use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Tests\TestCase;

class SampleDownloadTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function uploaded_file_downloads_correctly()
    {
        //keep a sample file inside projectroot/resources/files folder
        //create a file from it
        $exampleFile = new File(resource_path('files/test-file.png'))
        //copy that file to projectroot/storage/app/uploads folder
        Storage::putFileAs('/uploads', $exampleFile, 'test-file.png');

        //make request to file download url to get file 
        $response = $this->get("/files/file/download/url");

        //check whethe response was ok
        $response->assertOk();
        $response->assertHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png')
        //check whether file exists in path
        Storage::assertExists('/uploads/test-file.png');
        //do some more assertions.....
        //after test delete the file from storage path
        Storage::delete('uploads/test-file.png');
        //check whether file was deleted
        Storage::assertMissing('/uploads/test-file.png');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use fake file storage feature of Laravel (mocking):

```
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

$file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('filename.ext', $sizeInKb)->store('filename.ext');
```

If you want to create a text/csv file with a **specific content** you can use this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

$header = 'a,b,c';
$row1 = 'x,y,z';
$row2 = 's,f,t';
$row3 = 'r,i,o';

$content = implode("\n", [$header, $row1, $row2, $row3]);

$file = UploadedFile::fake()->createWithContent('filename.ext', $content)->store('filename.ext');
```

You can find this methods definitions in `Illuminate\Http\Testing\FileFactory`

Comment: i don't think `->store('filename.ext')` is necessary

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a new file directly or copy a specific test file for example:

```
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

// for simple text files or if the content doesn't matter
Storage::disk('avatars')->put('avatar.jpg', 'some non-jpg content');

// if you need a specific file for your test
$file = new File(base_path('tests/resources/avatar.jpg'));
Storage::disk('avatars')->putFileAs('/', $file, 'avatar.jpg');
```

The latter function will take the `$file` and copy it under the given name `avatar.jpg` to the given directory `/` on the disk `avatars`. You can read more about it [in the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#storing-files).

Answer (score 0):

What you could use to solve that problem is fixtures. Laravel's testing framework is essentially PHPUnit, so I see no reason why it would not work.

define your test like so:

```
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {
    protected function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        Storage::fake('avatars');
        $uploadResponse = $this->json('POST', '/avatar', [
          'avatar' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg')
        ]);
    }
    protected function tearDown() {
        parent::tearDown();
    }
    public function testAvatarUpload() {
        // Download the first avatar
        $response = $this->get('/download/avatar/1');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

`setUp` and `tearDown` get called, respectively, before and after each test in the class. So, before each test method, `setUp` will wipe the `avatars` fake disk and run the request. As there is nothing to do after a test (since `Storage::fake()` replaces the disk if it already exists), the method is empty; I left it here purely to make the example complete.

There's some pretty good documentation [on here](https://www.dyclassroom.com/phpunit/phpunit-fixtures-setup-and-teardown) about this feature of PHPunit.

Regarding putting the file on there, once you have your `setUp` working correctly, there's nothing stopping you from throwing the file on it.